# How to include tf.py_func code in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, autoencoder

I am currently getting an error: `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()` when compiling my code, and I am not sure where the error is coming from.

Basically what I am trying to do is implement an Autoencoder in Keras that performs an arbitrary operation on the output of the encoder as the decoder. It is not feasible to implement the code in `tf_render_vst` using tensorflow operations. I have all the code written but I don't understand why it will not work. Is this possible? - my code so far is pasted below:

```
def tf_render_vst(x):
    return tf.py_func(render_vst, [x], tf.float32)

def render_vst(x):
    patch = rt.label_to_patch(x, fixed_params)
    audio = rt.render_patch(patch, vst_path, render_config)
    spect = rt.stft(audio)
    return spect


input_img = Input(shape=(input_shape))

# encoding Layers
...
x = Dense(output_shape, activation='linear')(x)
encoded = Activation(soft_quantization)(x)

# Decoding Layer (render patch)
decoded = Lambda(tf_render_vst, trainable = False)(encoded)

# Full Model
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)

# First Half of Autoencoder - the bit I'm interested in
encoder = Model(input_spec, encoded)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

Thank you in advance!

Edit: Here is the error message -

`~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights, sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, **kwargs)
    720                 if target is None or K.is_placeholder(target):
    721                     if target is None:
--> 722                         target = K.placeholder(ndim=len(shape),
    723                                                name=name + '_target',
    724                                                sparse=K.is_sparse(self.outputs[i]),`

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: I think it is because `tf_render_vst ` does not define gradients, and thus cause a problem in back-propagation.

Comment: @user36624 ah, of course. I'll try adding gradients now.